# speed up transition_reveal and some more associated questions

Tags: r, gganimate

I have been playing seriously with gganimate on trying to create a story of rank movement of some quality indictors of the states of India . while I could create an animation up to certain level of the whole story I have on mind but still it is far off from the whole picture.

here is what I came up with till now 
[image]

The data behind the animated rank movement across months per state of the country is as below

```
> dput(onlyrank)
structure(list(`Short name` = c("AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", 
"AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", 
"AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", 
"AP", "AP", "AP", "AP", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", 
"AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", 
"AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", 
"AS", "AS", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", 
"BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", 
"BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", 
"CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", 
"CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", 
"CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "CG", "DL", "DL", 
"DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", 
"DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", 
"DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "DL", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", 
"GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", 
"GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", 
"GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", 
"GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", 
"GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "GJ", 
"GJ", "GJ", "GJ", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", 
"HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", 
"HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", 
"HP", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", 
"HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", 
"HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "HR", "JH", 
"JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", 
"JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", 
"JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JH", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", 
"JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "JM", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", 
"KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", 
"KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", "KL", 
"KL", "KL", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", 
"KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", 
"KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", "KO", 
"KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", 
"KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", 
"KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "MH", "MH", 
"MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", 
"MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", 
"MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MH", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", 
"MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", 
"MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", 
"MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MP", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", 
"MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", 
"MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", "MU", 
"MU", "MU", "MU", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", 
"OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", 
"OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "PJ", 
"PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", 
"PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", 
"PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "PJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", 
"RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", 
"RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", 
"RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "RJ", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", 
"TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", 
"TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", 
"TN", "TN", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", 
"UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", 
"UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", 
"UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", 
"UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", 
"UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", 
"UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-E", "UP-W", 
"UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", 
"UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", 
"UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", 
"UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "UP-W", "WB", "WB", "WB", 
"WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", 
"WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", 
"WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB", "WB"), Date = structure(c(17879, 
17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 
17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 
17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 
17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 
17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 
17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 
17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 
17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 
17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 
17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 
17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 
17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 
17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 
17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 
17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 
17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 
17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 
17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 
17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 
17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 
17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 
17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 
17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 
17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 
17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 
17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 
17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 
17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 
17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 
17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 
17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 
17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 
17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 
17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 
17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 
17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 
17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 
17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 
17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 
17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 
17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 
17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 
17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 
17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 
17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 
17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 
17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 
17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 
17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 
17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 
17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 
17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 
17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 
17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 
17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 
17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 
17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 
17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 
17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 
17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 
17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 
17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 
17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 
17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 
17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 
17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 
17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 
17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 
17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 
17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 
17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 
17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 
17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 
17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 
17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 
17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 
17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 
17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 
17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 
17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 
17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 
17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 
17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 
17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 
17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 
17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 
17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 
17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 
17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 
17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 
17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 
17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 
17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 17879, 
17880, 17881, 17882, 17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 
17889, 17890, 17891, 17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897, 
17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 
17907, 17908, 17909), class = "Date"), variable = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), class = "factor", .Label = c("sessionrank", "voltedroprank", 
"mutecallraterank", "ipthroughputrank", "hosrrank", "cqirank", 
"rankofmeanrank")), value = c(7L, 10L, 10L, 22L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 
8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 13L, NA, 8L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 26L, 24L, 22L, 24L, 
27L, 24L, 24L, 18L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 21L, 24L, 28L, NA, 26L, 
28L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 22L, 28L, 24L, 22L, 
22L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 27L, NA, NA, 26L, 28L, 23L, 
23L, 27L, 24L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
23L, 21L, 26L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 25L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 
15L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 20L, NA, NA, 19L, 15L, 16L, 
15L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 19L, 18L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 17L, NA, 17L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 
15L, 16L, 20L, 21L, 19L, NA, 21L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 20L, NA, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 18L, 25L, 27L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 25L, 23L, NA, 21L, 17L, 
24L, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, 19L, 24L, 27L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 27L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 8L, 
10L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 
8L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 22L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 9L, NA, 19L, 15L, 
4L, NA, 18L, 17L, 14L, 17L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 21L, 
17L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, NA, 14L, 15L, 14L, 7L, 8L, 14L, 
15L, 11L, 9L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 18L, 15L, 17L, 12L, 
17L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 18L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 18L, 16L, 14L, 
20L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 21L, 15L, 16L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 
11L, 14L, 11L, NA, 10L, 7L, 15L, 4L, 16L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 
6L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 
13L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 15L, 16L, 10L, 13L, NA, 9L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 
7L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 15L, 9L, 17L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 
4L, 12L, NA, 8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 20L, 22L, 18L, 12L, 12L, 17L, 15L, NA, NA, 
NA, 11L, NA, NA, 18L, 16L, 13L, 11L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 16L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 24L, 23L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 26L, 
25L, NA, 22L, 18L, 25L, NA, NA, 26L, 25L, 20L, 23L, 26L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25L, NA, NA, NA, 23L, 26L, 25L, 
26L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 19L, 26L, 25L, 27L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 27L, NA, 
25L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 20L, 23L, 21L, 
24L, 25L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 23L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 20L, 
17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 
14L, 19L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 16L, NA, 9L, 17L, 15L, 
16L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 18L, 20L, NA, 17L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 20L, 
17L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 17L, 14L, 16L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 14L, 
9L, 3L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 
5L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 10L, NA, 9L, 11L, 14L, 
12L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 19L, 12L, 17L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 8L, NA, 5L, 11L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 27L, 25L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 17L, 24L, 
23L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 
22L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 17L, 
15L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 12L, 7L, NA, 6L, 
17L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 18L, 17L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 11L, 
14L, 22L, 21L, 20L, NA, 24L, 22L, 21L, 16L, 23L, NA, 26L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, NA, 20L, 23L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 
21L, 18L, 24L, 19L, 21L, 21L), sequence = 1:868), row.names = c(NA, 
-868L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000231ef0>, index = structure(integer(0), "`__Short name`" = integer(0)))
```

head  and tail of the data

```
> head(onlyrank)
   Short name       Date       variable value sequence
1:         AP 2018-12-14 rankofmeanrank     7        1
2:         AP 2018-12-15 rankofmeanrank    10        2
3:         AP 2018-12-16 rankofmeanrank    10        3
4:         AP 2018-12-17 rankofmeanrank    22        4
5:         AP 2018-12-18 rankofmeanrank    10        5
6:         AP 2018-12-19 rankofmeanrank     9        6
> > tail(onlyrank)
   Short name       Date       variable value sequence
1:         WB 2019-01-08 rankofmeanrank    21      863
2:         WB 2019-01-09 rankofmeanrank    18      864
3:         WB 2019-01-10 rankofmeanrank    24      865
4:         WB 2019-01-11 rankofmeanrank    19      866
5:         WB 2019-01-12 rankofmeanrank    21      867
6:         WB 2019-01-13 rankofmeanrank    21      868
```

and the gganimate+ggplot code is

```
r1 <- ggplot(onlyrank,aes(x=Date,y=value,group=`Short name`))+
      geom_line(aes(size=2,colour=`Short name`,group=`Short name`),
                    alpha=0.9,show.legend = FALSE)+ 
      geom_point(aes(colour=`Short name`),size=3,show.legend = FALSE)+ 
      geom_segment(aes(xend=lastdate,yend=value),linetype=2)+
      geom_text(aes(x=lastdate+1,y=value,
                    label=paste0(`Short name`,"(",value,")")))+
      scale_y_reverse()+
      coord_cartesian(clip="off")+
      transition_reveal(along=sequence)+
      ease_aes()

animate(r1,renderer = gifski_renderer(file="ranking.gif"),
        width = 1280, height = 720,nframes = 200)
```

so far so good.. based on the animation that is created.. I have some probelems and some aspirations

**problems**

1.My geom_points seems to not show up..why?( some problem in group? eeven if explicitity set group aes it does not help)

**update 28/1**
after thoroughly understanding API I realized I need to add group properly in the geom_point  as below

```
geom_point(aes(group =sequence),colour="black",size=3,show.legend = FALSE)
```

and now the points are visible duly

2.The animation across the Dates does not render covering all dates, the rendering ( tweening?) comes in lumps and chunks over a few dates together ..does not seem to freeflow.. I tried with few options of animate with different nframes all the way upto 700, fps in animate all the way upto 25..the sporadic sense is still there..i seriously doubt on some fundamental mistakes I am doing ..so what is that mistake I need to correct?

**Update 28/01**
I scaled the nframes to 3000 and eventually and the animation is now smooth but the gif size increases to whooping 29 MB(I am unable to upload due to size)..**so question how to trim it down to smaller size?**

so finally the code looks now as below

```
lastdate<-sort(unique(onlyrank$Date),decreasing = TRUE)[1]+1
r1 <- ggplot(onlyrank,aes(x=Date,y=value))+
  geom_line(aes(colour=`Short name`,group=`Short name`),size=2,alpha=0.9,show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_point(aes(group =sequence),colour="black",size=3,show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_segment(aes(xend=lastdate,yend=value,group=`Short name`),linetype=2)+
  geom_text(aes(x=lastdate+1,y=value,label=paste0(`Short name`,"(",value,")"),group=`Short name`,colour=`Short name`))+
  scale_y_reverse()+
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")+
  transition_reveal(along=sequence)+
  ease_aes()

animate(r1,renderer = renderer = gifski_renderer(file="ranking.gif"),width = 1280, height = 720,nframes = 3000)
```

**update 02-02**
using  the fantastic **gifsicle** able to trim down it to smaller version
[image]

**Aspiration**

3.i want to set the visibility(?alpha) of the geom_line for the state to minimum post it is fully shown across date.. so as to make sure the state which is currently being shown is not lost in the clutter

**update 28/01**
This one is still unaddressed.. I do not yet have slightest clue if transition_reveal can work with enter_* & exit_*...any help

**update 02/02**

still the clutter is high.. so how do I grey each line after it goes thru the animation ...

## ideas??

Any one care to take a peek and advice?

Best Regards
Rajib